# Why getting words which not matching condition?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, docx

I am trying to find out why am I getting also the first words from the list, even they are not matching (or they are ?) the simple if-else condition.

I have a simple "Lorem Ipsum" docx file, and I put the text to the list with python. And when I am looping through this list with a simple condition for matching the words with "." and "," to get purely only the words, I am getting also the first words of the sentence. But not all. Not sure where the magic is hidden.

Can you have a look and share your endless wisdom?
I bet it is something stupid, that I didn't face yet.

Many thanks anyway.

here is the simple scratch:

Got all words into string and split it with " "

```
all_words = get_text(file)
updated_list = all_words.split(" ")
```

Then just simple if else give me result

```
for word in updated_list:
    if "." in word:            
        new_word = word.replace(".", "")
        print(new_word)
    elif "," in word:      
        new_word = word.replace(",", "")
        print(new_word)
```

- amet <--- first word where is ","
- elit <--- same for "." risus ...
- nec ... and so on...
- euismod
- fringilla ...
- Integer <--- HERE IS PROBLEM - this is the first word of the sentence. Why it is here? No "," or "." in the word.
- vestibulum
- ...
- ...

Do I need to be more specific with the condition?
Am I missing something?

Many thanks

Comment: You could make sure that there is no `Integer` followed by a comma or a period by running a quick grep command: `grep 'Integer,\.' filename.txt`.

Comment: Without seeing your version of "Lorem Ipsum", I cannot understand what exactly is happening (for example, the standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s, does not contain the word Integer, see https://www.lipsum.com/). Among the exotic versions - considering that you are reading text from a .docx file, it is even possible that the font color of some dots or commas is white, so you cannot see them, but Python does.

Answer (score 1):

For Thomas:
I tried the grep and it looks like there is no any character after word:

```
$ grep 'Integer,\.' Original_Text.docx 
$
```

For Алексей Р:
I grab the text from the first lorem ipsum site on google: https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html  and generate from default (5 paragraphs).

Word Integer is the first one of the second paragraph.

For MANSOOR BASHA SYED:
I tried and it gave a word without the "." or ","

here is excerpt:

> sollicitudin.
> sollicitudin
> ligula.
> ligula
> imperdiet,
> imperdiet
> tincidunt.
>
> Integer
> tincidunt
>
> Integer
> vestibulum.
> vestibulum
> neque.

(aah, I dont understand why the list cannot be alligned, still showing words in line.)

Edit 2:
OK OK. I am taking this back. Just found out that the page is generating randomly text every time. So I cannot generate the same wrong words order for you.

Answer (score 0):

Print word before replacing ,. values then you can it if it really has it

```py
for word in updated_list:
    if "." in word:
        print(word)            
        new_word = word.replace(".", "")
        print(new_word)
    elif "," in word:
        print(word)      
        new_word = word.replace(",", "")
        print(new_word)
```